# C# Specified Cast is Not Valid

Tags: c#

I want to get autocomplete for text box given in parameter

```
 public static void GetProductsForTextBox(TextBox MyProductTextBox)
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new   AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Title FROM Products", Database.con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Database.con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 MyCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["Title"].ToString())); 
            }
            reader.Close();
            Database.con.Close();
            MyProductTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException exc)
        { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); }
        catch (Exception exc)
        { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); }
        finally
        {   Database.con.Close();  }
    }
```

Specified Cast is not valid

Comment: And Exception is not catched by InvalidCastException;

Comment: MyProductTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection; This Line Generate The Error

Comment: Have you set the `AutoCompleteSource` property to `CustomSource`?

Comment: @sellotape Should that cause an exception if not?

Comment: @bart-hofland - not sure, but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) specifically says you must.

Comment: OK. Yes, I understand you have to set it. But as far as I could see, it was not an issue in my test app when it's not set/changed. If not set to `CustomSource`, the autocomplete simply does not work with `AutoCompleteCustomSource`. My test app did not "crash" due to an exception, however. So I don't think that setting/changing the `AutoCompleteSource` property will solve the exception issue here.

Comment: @BartHofland - sure; it was just something to try.
AhmadAli - can you add the whole exception stack trace to your question please?

Comment: On which line you are getting `Specified Cast is not valid` exception?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. I tried the following in a small WinForms test app (having a Form named `Form1` with only a TextBox named `MyProductTextBox`) and I had no problems with it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    try
    {
        MyCollection.Add("Foo");
        MyCollection.Add("Bar");

        MyProductTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;

        MyProductTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        MyProductTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```